# Sum of $k$ consecutive term divisible by $k+1$

Tags: number-theory

Is there an infinite sequence of positive integers such that for every positive integer $k$ sum of every $k$ consecutive terms of sequence is divisible by $k+1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were such a sequence, let $n$ be a number that does not divide $a_1$.

Now consider the first $2n-1$ terms, grouped and summed as

$$(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1})+(a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{2n-2})+a_{2n-1}$$

This sum is divisible by $2n$, hence by $n$.  But each of the sums in parentheses is also divisible by $n$, hence $n$ divides $a_{2n-1}$.  But $n$ also divides the sum $a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{2n-1}$, so it divides $a_{n+1}+a_{2n-2}$, and thus also divides $a_n$.  By similar reasoning, $n$ divides $a_2+\cdots+a_n$, hence divides $a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}$, hence divides $a_1$, which contradicts the assumption that $n$ does *not* divide $a_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not rearranging it in the form$$a_1+(a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n)+(a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{2n-2}+a_{2n-1})$$